# How to add new column depending on other one in SQL with regular expression

Tags: mysql, sql, presto

With this query:

```
    SELECT  value,
            type
    FROM "my_data"
```

I get a table:

```
value   type
17      harm_2
10      harm
17      harm
11      sharm_9
76      coins
```

I want to add new column is_harm with values harm/not_harm depending on column type, sports if there is word harm in that column it must be "harm" and if not "not_harm". So this table should look like this:

```
value   type        is_harm      
17      harm_2      harm
10      harm        harm
17      harm        harm
11      sharm_9     not_harm
76      coins       not_harm
```

How to do that with regular expressions? As you see there are values like sharm_9

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `^` metacharacter, which matches the beginning of the string:

```
SELECT value, type, 
  IF(type REGEXP '^harm', 'harm', 'not_harm') AS is_harm
FROM "my_data";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the starting words with harm you can use  `LEFT` function.
Keep in mind below query will not work for results like `2_harm`.

```
select `value`,
       `type`,
        IF(LEFT(`type`,4)='harm','harm','not_harm' ) as is_harm 
from test;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/85